# Is there a way to use ungreedy matching in JavaScript for regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode, non-greedy

I wonder if there is a way to use ungreedy matching in JavaScript? I tried the U modifer, but it doesn't seem to work.

I want to write a small BBCode parser in JavaScript, but without ungreedy matching it isn't possible (at least as far as I see it) to do something like this:

```
'[b]one[/b] two [b]three[/b]'.replace( /\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/, '<b>$1</b>' );
```

But such a replacement would be nice since there is no need to check for HTML validity then. Unclosed markups will stay simple text.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use `?` after `*` or `+` to make it ungreedy, e.g. `(.*?)`

Comment: Incredible, but it just works! Thanks.
in other enviroments, the flag /u (ungreedy) can be used. But for javascript methods is not available (with exception of nodejs methods, i think)

Comment: Please could you try to explain the logic behind this trick ?

Comment: @St3an there isn't a logic behind this trick to explain. `*` and `*?` are two different quantifiers. `*` is the greedy quantifier (match zero to unlimited times as many times as possible) `*?` is the lazy quantifier (match zero to unlimited times as few times as possible).
Fun fact: Using the flag `U` (Ungreedy) seems to revers the meaning. However the flag isn't supported by js and the lowercase `u` is the unicode-flag.

Answer (score 4):

I'm late, but I'll post the regex anyway.

```
'[b]one[/b] two [b]three[/b]'.replace( /\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/g, '<b>$1</b>' );
```